# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FirebaseShutdown', reason: 'Firebase error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, xmpp, chat

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FirebaseShutdown', reason: 'Firebase error. Please ensure that you spelled the name of your Firebase correctly' in ios.
```

Can any one help me solve this issue?
Using this demo for real time message:
https://github.com/firebase/ios-swift-chat-example

Is there any demo for real time chat in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is actually from calling [`Firebase initWithUrl:]` with a `URL` that isn't backed by a valid Firebase.

This exception is thrown so that you as a developer know that the `Firebase` you're connecting to is invalid.

If you put in the right `Firebase` `URL`, you shouldn't be getting this error.

```
Could you explain the situation in which you might need to connect to a Firebase that may not be valid?
```

**Note:- You will need to check your base `URL` for the `Firebase`, Because you have try to access data from the wrong URL**

Comment: Base url available in firebase console?

Comment: can you mention exact line in question where application getting Crash

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FirebaseInternalError', reason: 'For a custom Firebase host, you must first set your authentication server before using authentication features! , currently new error found